# Live HTML editor for web-designers

Tags: html, live

am creating a simple hosting website for my work but Many Software's Have A Splitted Side of view To Edit The Code And The To See The Updated Codes like Dreamweaver

Am Searching For A Live Editor Where i Can Work Directly From The HTML Page

Example: If There Is A Box In The Middle And I need To move it down i simply Click On It And Drag It With My Mouse. 
Is There Any Software Can Do That?

Comment: what you're looking is called WYSIWYG [What You See is What You Get] editor. search with this term. also look for how to ask question better way in StackOverFlow.com

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, one option you could look at is https://www.pagecloud.com/

Answer (score 0):

heay u can use adobe muse it is simply drag and drop

[Adobe Muse](http://muse.adobe.com/)

Comment: Mandar You Cant Import A Design What Was Already Done An HTML Page In Muse You Can Only Start A New Site,